# GCP Dataproc: create cluster with stackdriver activated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Using GCP, I instantiate workflows for my processing. I'd like to activate Stackdriver logging to have more metrics (see https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/stackdriver-logging).

From documentation, I should set the property:

```
dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable=true
```

My workflow template looks like:

```
placement:
  managedCluster:
    clusterName: my-cluster
    config:
      gceClusterConfig:
        zoneUri: europe-west1-d
      masterConfig:
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-4
      workerConfig:
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-4
        numInstances: 10
```

Where should I set this property?

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below should work.

Since the API hierarchy is deeply nested, you can build the initial template using `gcloud dataproc workflow-templates` interface, `describe` command will give you the correct YAML or JSON. You can then do fast iteration using `instantiate-inline` from the local file.

```
placement:
  managedCluster:
    clusterName: my-cluster
    config:
      gceClusterConfig:
        zoneUri: europe-west1-d
      masterConfig:
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-4
      workerConfig:
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-4
        numInstances: 10
      softwareConfig:
        properties:
          dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable: true
```

Comment: Thx. Doing so, I get the following error: `ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.workflow-templates.import) File not found /Users/rolintocour/exec -l /bin/bash/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/schemas/dataproc/v1/PropertiesValue.yaml`. Any idea?

Comment: I had to use `gcloud beta dataproc` to make it work. Thx!

Comment: Sorry about that. It should be fixed in `gcloud` that went out this week.